# Two floats to first element of a tuple

Tags: python, dataframe, tuples

I have a dataframe with Lat and Long columns (float). I am using a library that requires lat, long input to be of the form ((Lat,Long)) where the lat, long is the first element of a tuple in a tuple of at least 2 elements. i.e.

```
coords = ((37.275561,-121.964134),)
type(coords)
> tuple
type(coords[0])
>tuple
```

I have tried ast literal_eval as well as zip in these sorts of calls:

```
df.assign(coords=[*zip(df.Lat, df.Lon)])

df['coords'] = df['Lat'].map(str) + ',' + df['Lon'].map(str)
literal_eval(df['coords'][0])
```

Both of these methods creates a 2 element tuple

```
t = literal_eval(df['coords'][0])
(37.275561, -121.964134)

t[0] = 37.275561 <----What both of the above calls make.

t[0] = (37.275561, -121.964134)  <--- WHAT I Want it to be.
```

Ideally i would just be able to call something to the dataframe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to obtain one of the below (I used sample data):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Lat": range(1,10,2), "Lon": range(10, 15)})
# 1st option
df["coords"]=df[["Lat", "Lon"]].agg(tuple, axis=1)
# 2nd option
df["coords2"]=df[["Lat", "Lon"]].agg(lambda x: (tuple(x),), axis=1)
```

Outputs:

```py
   Lat  Lon   coords     coords2
0    1   10  (1, 10)  ((1, 10),)
1    3   11  (3, 11)  ((3, 11),)
2    5   12  (5, 12)  ((5, 12),)
3    7   13  (7, 13)  ((7, 13),)
4    9   14  (9, 14)  ((9, 14),)
```

Comment: Thanks! Option 2 is what works for me. I still don't understand why the other library I am using is so strict in its input but the options for offline reverse geocoding are slim.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.itertuples` with `list` comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10, 2)), columns=["Lat", "Lon"])
[(x, ) for x in df.itertuples(False, None)]
```

Output:

```
[((0.32427121647946533, 0.027607442056747478),),
 ((0.7978575521459672, 0.10246067888630661),),
 ((0.7604534847597701, 0.22688737398122827),),
 ((0.7772166981423476, 0.4517511790606119),),
 ((0.05758468082099388, 0.5715157313903072),),
 ((0.24301536293666137, 0.15681071972461658),),
 ((0.7856579500084773, 0.7396643931774448),),
 ((0.529357848080448, 0.02914409356782033),),
 ((0.7636110612200776, 0.9182403706928705),),
 ((0.14171738807504053, 0.17194731426254195),)]
```